# infinite scroll react with push parameter to url on scrolling , seo fix

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, infinite-scroll

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly

as described in this article infinite scroll should have pagination for better SEO performance , what should be done , is to create scroll this will change page parameter in URL when some part items scrolled down and back

I don't see any working solutions on the internet , only this example http://scrollsample.appspot.com/static/main.js . Maybe someone know how to solve it or have some working examples how to make it ?